# window.history.replaceState() work after form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button

I have a button that submits a file to a link when it is pressed. The URL after the form is submitted contains query parameters that I want to hide. The best thing I could think of is using window.history.replaceState, however for some reason it is not working the way I want it to. My code is pasted below. I notice that right before the form is submitted the URL is changed, but I want the URL after the form is submitted to change.

Javascript:

```
async function finalSubmission (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let urlFinal = "https://<website to upload to>"+"?<query parameters>";
    e.target.action = urlFinal;
    e.target.submit();
    var currentUrl = window.location.href;
    var baseUrl = currentUrl.split('?')[0];
    var newUrl = baseUrl + "?submit=done";
    window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, newUrl);
}
```

HTML:

```html
<form method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id = finalfilesubmit onsubmit = "finalSubmission(event)">
    <label for = "myfile"><strong>Select a file to be uploaded:</label>
    <input class = choosebutton type = "file" id = "myfile" name = "filename">
<input class = uploadbutton type = "submit" value = "Upload File"></form>
```

Comment: FYI: `var baseUrl = currentUrl.split('?')[0];` === `var baseUrl = location.hostname`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you submit the form, the browser navigates from the page containing the form (**A**) to the URL specified in the `action` of the form element (**B**).

You want the browser to navigate to **B** but claim to be on **C**.

There is no way for **A** to directly cause the browser to land **B** and claim to be anywhere other than **B**.

You have several options.

- **B** could return a `Location` header and perform a [`303` redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#redirection_messages) to **C**.
- JavaScript on **B** could call `replaceState`. It could use information passed in the query string of the URL (as specified by the `action`) to determine what arguments to pass to `replaceState`.
- JavaScript on **A** could send the form data to the URL in the `action` using Ajax instead of submitting the form. Then it could update the view using DOM manipulation and call `replaceState`.

The first one is the simplest and least likely to go wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using the first method and it works perfectly!